# Adding a new domain in IRedMail

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, domain, iredmail

I have a small Ubuntu 16.04.3 email server and I choose the easiest way using IRedMail. Email and Roundcube now works for my primary domain, but I'm having problems adding a new domain. Let's say I have olddomain.com and newdomain.com.

- I configured DNS at my DNS provider
- I added newdomain.com in IRedMail Admin panel
- I generated a key using:

  ```
    amavisd-new genrsa newdomain.com.pem
  ```

and if I run "amavisd-new testkeys" I get:

> TESTING#1 olddomain.com: dkim._domainkey.olddomain.com => pass
>
> TESTING#2 newdomain.com: dkim._domainkey.newdomain.com => pass

- I think I did not touch the nginx configuration
- Restarted everything

Now if I browse to mail.newdomain.com to use Roundcube I get redirected to mail.olddomain.com. I'm not sure if this is the default behavior, but it's not what I would prefer. I would like email users of newdomain.com be able to use Roundcube on mail.newdomain.com. How can I set that up?

Comment: Hm.. my question might also belong to the Superuser SE..

Comment: Sounds like a silly question, but have you tried curling it instead of using your browser to check that the redirect isn't cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all you need to do is to create another virtual host in Apache or another server block in Nginx for the new mail domain. However, the Apache/Nginx directory structure is heavily modified by iRedmail, which makes the process a little complicated.

To see the exact steps for Nginx, check out my iRedMail tutorial: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/set-up-iredmail-multiple-domains-nginx

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks. IRedMail modifies nginx confinguration a lot and that was the reason I was so lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create configuration files for the new domain.

> In case you have one installation of Roundcube to serve multiple domains hosted on one server you can create host-specific config files. These files have to be named like .inc.php and are saved in Roundcube's config directory.

Check  [this link](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Configuration:-Multi-Domain-Setup)